# phonegap.js is missing in "phonegap run android " but exits in " phonegap build android"

Tags: cordova

- when in run  CMD (phonegap build android) the phonegap.js is created
      in platforms/android/wwww/assets
      but when i run (phonegap run android) the file is deleted